# How to get a node with Xpath which has only digits in the text attribute?

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I have this kind of DOM:

```
<a>abc</a>
<a>def</a>
<a>13456</a>
<a>gh564</a>
```

I want to get the element  which contains only digits.

I could do it by getting all the elements  and looping them to check if text() is digits, but I would prefer to find it directly with Xpath. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the solution using the `matches()` function, **here are two more solutions**:

```
//*[. castable as xs:integer]

//*[normalize-space() and not(translate(., '0123456789', ''))])
```

The 2nd solution can be used on a pure XPath 1 - (only) supporting platform.

---

**XSLT-based verification**:

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select=
      "(//*[. castable as xs:integer],
        //*[normalize-space() and not(translate(., '0123456789', ''))])"/>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>
    <a>abc</a>
    <a>def</a>
    <a>13456</a>
    <a>gh564</a>
</t>
```

**evaluates both XPath expressions and copies to the output the results of these evaluations**:

```
<a>13456</a>
<a>13456</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `//a[number() = number()]`, but that would work for floating point content like `<a>3.14</a>` too, so perhaps `//a[matches(., '^[0-9]+$')]`. Or the old, XPath 1, `translate` test: `//a[not(translate(., '0123456789', ''))]`.

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 2.0 you can use the matches() function with a regular expression.